# ActiveX or BHO (internet explorer)

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

I need some help from the browser plugin/extension gurus :)

Whats difference between BHO and activeX? Which one is harder?

My purpose is to inject 3rd party script.

Btw has IE something like localStorage in chrome and ff?

Thanks

Comment: `localStorage` is supported in IE8+.

Answer (score 3):

BHOs are loaded into the IE process at startup and are always running.  ActiveX controls are webpage specific objects loaded on demand by a given page and their lifetime is tied to the lifetime of the document.  Both are COM objects.

They are equally hard for different reasons.

Either one can inject script, but my guess is you want a BHO.

IE added support for web storage in version 8.